# Datepicker change date get the event dont work

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I tried many things but nothing work, also set date didnt work.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
    <input type='text' class="fechaRegistro form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  });
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('setDate', new Date());
});

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker().on("input change", function(e) {
  alert("Date changed: ", e.target.value);
});
```

Comment: Your `change` event handler is outside the document.ready handler. It needs to be inside it.

Comment: Agreed with @RoryMcCrossan